# CloudKit: are reliable realtime updates possible?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I have a `CKDatabaseSubscription` set up, with `shouldSendContentAvailable` set to true, and `soundName` set to an empty string.

It works great - except when a user has 'background app refresh' turned off on their device - notifications are not received, unless the device is charging. That seems to be the expected behaviour, given the `shouldSendContentAvailable` flag.

I don't mind that background updates never come through, but it seems that with two devices side by side, with the app in the foreground, changes on one device are not forwarded to the other when background app refresh is disabled.

That is unfortunate, although it seems like an edge case that a user would have the app open on both devices and this setting disabled. It would still be nice to fix this edge case though.

I could manually check for changes every once in a while, but that seems wasteful, especially since it is only edge cases that need this. Has anyone discovered a way to reliably receive these notifications while the app is in the foreground, even with background app refresh disabled? Or perhaps there is some other way to send and receive real time updates that isn't so obvious?

Comment: Have you implemented `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in order to process the incoming notification and trigger the sync?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes - as mentioned, notifications are working well when the user has 'background app refresh' turned on.

Comment: I just ran a test; I disabled background refresh for my app on my phone and then launched the app and left it  running on screen; It didn't make any difference whether the phone was charging or not, whether the app was running under Xcode or not; if background refresh is disabled I didn't get any push notifications; which is to be expected.  I noticed that if background refresh is disabled then I don't get a call to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` on app startup; so perhaps you could use that to decide whether to perform periodic sync.

Comment: @Paulw11 odd that I'm getting notifications while charging and you're not - although the docs are deliberately vague on when and how the content available pushes are delivered, so I guess there could be many factors involved. I do find it odd that you don't get a call back to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, because that call is independent of CloudKit and can be used to register pushes that aren't of a content available type - so a call back should still be received. Are you sure that's what you're seeing?

Comment: My app doesn't use notifications for any other purpose, so it doesn't request notification permissions; it simply calls `registerForRemoteNotifications()` on start up.  I found that if I started my app with background refresh disabled and then enabled background refresh I then got a call to `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications`. You can see my code in the `Example` folder here - https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3